# upgrading hard drive on toshiba satellite 5200 

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, upgrade

I have [this](http://www.toshiba.ca/web/product.grp?lg=en&section=1&group=223&product=878&part=516#spectop) beautiful & old laptop  and would like to replace hard drive.
I've purchased samsung 120GB hard drive and exchange hard drives.
When I turn on computer my laptop doesn't recognize hard drive at all. It doesn't find nothing under master drive.
What am I doing wrong, and is it possible to make this upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: Samsung 120GB hard drive I've purchased:
http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/pc-peripherals/hard-disk-drive/25-pata-hdd/HM121HC/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail

Answer (score 0):

the upgrade 'should' be possible, according to the **[spec sheet](http://www.toshiba.ca/web/product.grp?section=1&group=223&product=878)** this laptop is expandable up to 120 GB (an indication that the the controller does have 48-bit LBA support).

can post the model of the hard disk drive you bought?

Comment: Here it is:
http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/pc-peripherals/hard-disk-drive/25-pata-hdd/HM121HC/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail